# how to print a ascii string without storing in a variable assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Basically, I want to print I.e. "0x41414141" or "AAAA" in assembly by directly storing it to `ecx`, I tried below but it is not working:

```
SECTION .data
    buf: db "Hello", 5
SECTION .text
global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 0x41414141
    push eax
    pop ecx
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov edx, 4
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Also tried stuff such as `mov ecx, 0x41414141` but had no luck.

Compiling the code with `nasm -g -f elf -F dwarf ./shell.asm && ld -m elf_i386 -o shell shell.o` in a arc: `Linux kali 5.2.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.2.9-2kali1 (2019-08-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: There's no system call that does this for you. You'll have to convert the number `0x41414141` into the string `"0x41414141"` yourself, and then print that string.

Comment: Moreover, the `write` system call takes the data to be written in memory, not in a register.  There is no way around that.

Comment: If there was a "write single char" system call (as with DOS int 21h) you could do several of those in a row to write your data, but linux doesn't have that -- it has only write bytes from memory.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [NASM printing out time - code doesn't output anything](//stackoverflow.com/q/1242032), but that question has more fluff and no good simple answer that would really answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really possible using the `write` system call. The value in `ecx` should be a *pointer* to a buffer of bytes to be written, not the actual bytes themselves.

On another note you tell the `write` system call to write *five* bytes but `0x41414141` would be only four.

And if you want to print the hexadecimal number as the actual string `"0x41414141"` you need to first convert the number to a string, so that makes it even more impossible as it would be a string of ten (possible null-terminator not included) bytes (characters), which can't fit in a 32-bit (four byte) register.

Comment: @dude, I had changed the 5 byte to 4 byte, anyways update the question.

Comment: forgot to mention that I wanted to print "AAAA"

Comment: In that case you could replace `pop ecx` with `mov ecx,esp`. And then put an `add esp,4` after the system call has been performed to balance the stack.

Comment: @dude, woops that worked. so that would be, bc It move the esp pointer to ecx, right?